# Delete button is stuck when using selenium but normally it is working

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have created a script by which I want to unpublished an element and then delete all list present on the page. both options are to unpublished and delete. It appears that when we click on icon(so both elements displays when we click on icon)

Now when I am going to click on delete button then a pop-up for authorization should appear but this is not happening when I am using selenium while when I using site normally(without selenium) then it is working fine.

There are many unpublished and delete button present respective to each row.

I have also tried with JavascriptExecutor and Actions

My Code:-

```
List<WebElement> unpublishlink1 = d.findElements(By.cssSelector("a.action-publish.action_profile_unpublish"));
        List<WebElement> deletelink1 = d.findElements(By.cssSelector("em.icon16.icon16-delete"));

    WebElement deleted = null;
    for ( WebElement deletelink: deletelink1) {
        WebElement cogiconlink = d.findElement(By.className("device-action-menu-arrow"));
        cogiconlink.click();
        deleted=deletelink; 
    }
    for ( WebElement unpublishlink: unpublishlink1) { 
        while (unpublishlink.isDisplayed() || deleted.isDisplayed()  ) {

        if (unpublishlink.isDisplayed()) {
                unpublishPopup(d,unpublishlink, deleted);

        } else {
            deleteAlert(d,deleted);
        }
        }

        }

    }


public void unpublishPopup(WebDriver d,WebElement unpublishlink,WebElement deleted)
{
    unpublishlink.click();
    d.findElement(By.id("Unpublish_Profile"));
    d.findElement(By.id("UnpublishProfileReason")).sendKeys("lish");
    d.findElement(By.id("UnpublishProfilePassword")).sendKeys("@123");
    d.findElement(By.id("UnpublishProfileYes")).click();
    d.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    d.get(d.getCurrentUrl()); 
    deleteAlert(d, deleted);
}

public void deleteAlert(WebDriver d,WebElement deleted)
{
    d.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    d.get(d.getCurrentUrl());  
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(d, 10);
    WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(d.findElement(By.cssSelector("em.icon16.icon16-delete"))));
    WebElement deleteLink=d.findElement(By.cssSelector("em.icon16.icon16-delete"));
    deleteLink.click();
    //JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) d;
    //executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", deleteLink);
    d.switchTo().alert().accept();
    d.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    d.get(d.getCurrentUrl()); 
    System.out.println("going out");
    try{
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

My HTML Code:-

Icon code:-

```
<div class="device-action-menu">
<div class="device-action-menu-placeholder"></div>
<span class="device-action-menu-arrow"></span>
<ul class="device-action-menu-ul">
```

unpublish button code:-

```
            <li><a href="javascript:;" class="action-publish action_profile_unpublish" profilename="Test_Agent_1_Cleinrt" profileid="1764" rel="https://mysite/profilec/profileunpublish/1764" title="Unpublish Profile"><em class="icon16 icon16-wipe"></em></a></li>
```

delete button code :-

```
   <li><a href="javascript:;" class="action-delete delete_action" rel="https://mysite/profilec/delete/1434" title="Delete Profile"><em class="icon16 icon16-delete"></em></a></li>
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting back? Does it fail to click or is the action initiated and nothing happens? I have posted an answer that might help as I had similar problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this please:

```
JavascriptLibrary jsLib = new JavascriptLibrary();
jsLib.callEmbeddedSelenium(driver,"triggerMouseEventAt", element,"click", "0,0");**
```

Comment: thanks for sharing a new way to click but it is also not working